# How to optimize a database connection and query, to prevent MySQL run out of memory?

Tags: php

I have a class for my db connection, witch i try to use in order to limit the amount of connections to the server.

If i have a lot of users, the sql server crash due to run out of memory. it can be the server setup, or it can be related to the code? i would appreciate any suggestions here.

The __destruct kills the connection, but does it free the result in order to take on more query's?

I'm leaving the example code here:

```
class db{

    public $db_connection;


    public function __construct(){

        $this->db_connection = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","myuser","passwd","dbname");
        $this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8");

        if($this->db_connection->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to database: " . $db_connection->connect_error;
        }
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        return $this->db_connection->close();
    }
}
```

Initiate the db connection, usally i do this in header, so i can re-use the connection troughout the page.

```
$db = new db();
```

Typical query on a random page: (can be more on one page)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            $result = $db->db_connection->query("SELECT * FROM news");
            if ($result) { 
                while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {    
                    //some html code here
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried caching the DB results? either on disk or in-memory. Instead of hitting the DB for each request from each user for the same resource, see if delivering the resource from the cache makes sense instead of trying to optimize the DB load.

Comment: You may want to use [persistants connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504270/how-to-use-mysqli-persistent-connection-across-different-pages) to avoid having to open a new connection each time your user navigate your website.

Comment: Allright, i am using Apache2, PHP5 and MySQL, is there a plugin for apache or some extra module to install? or is it needed to run my_sql_free result after each query?

Comment: You should call _mysqli_free_result()_ to release memory after the while loop.

Comment: First performance task is to economize your query results. I mean, really you need all from your news table? Maybe you need just the X last registers, and maybe you need just quite fields. Not absolutely all.

Answer (score 0):

Every connection to your page is going to try and open a connection to MySQL. Every page load is going to be retrieving everything from the 'news' table.

There's a limit to how many connections MySQL can handle - once you hit that the page is going to break.

A PHP class will not limit the number of connections to the MySQL server. What will limit the number of connections is how many web server processes you run, and of those processes how many are executing PHP.

You should look into using some sort of local file based cache (e.g. a scheduled task writes the 'news' data out into a static html file, and each page load then just includes 'news.html'). This would allow you to remove the database connection and query from the rendering of the page.

Alternatively, use something like CloudFlare (assuming your pages are fairly static and are setting cache friendly headers)